# Is a Closed and Bounded Interval Required for Arzela-Ascoli?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, weak-convergence, arzela-ascoli

I am currently studying [a paper on weak solutions to the Navier-Stokes equations](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tmj/1178228767).

In this paper, the author sets $T>0$, and uses the time interval $[0,T)$ for all of his statements early on. However, we get to a point where, having constructed approximate solutions $u_m$, we wish to show uniform (with respect to time) weak convergence to some weak solution $u$, using the Arzela-Ascoli theorem.

At this point, the author suddenly switches to the **closed** time interval $[0,T]$. It seems that we must do this, as the statement of the Arzela-Ascoli theorem clearly stipulates that the interval our series of functions acts on be closed and bounded.

For $T<\infty$, this should be no problem. Our approximate solutions are continuous in $t$, so we can extend our functions to include the point $t=T$. The problem is that the paper never mentions any requirement that $T < \infty$.

Up until now, I have assumed that the reason why we use the half-closed interval $[0,T)$ for these studies of Navier-Stokes is because we are including the possibility that $T = \infty$. Is this mistaken?

My main question is, in order to use Arzela-Ascoli, are we forced to assume $T<\infty$ so that we can use the closed interval $[0,T]$? Or is there a way to apply Arzela-Ascoli on the interval $[0,\infty)$ so that we can still include the $T=\infty$ case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately Arzela-Ascoli requires the domain of the functions to be compact. For example take $f_n: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ defined by
$$ f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x \leq n \\
(x - n) & n \leq x \leq n + 1 \\
1 & x \geq n + 1.
\end{cases}$$
Then $\{f_n\}$ is bounded and equicontinuous however has no convergent subsequence since $\lVert f_n - f_m \rVert_{\infty} = 1$ for all $n \neq m$. Thus there is no convergent subsequence.

I haven't read the paper so there may be additional assumptions in this specific context that might help but in general Arzela-Ascoli requires a compact domain.

Comment: However, the sequence *is* locally uniform convergent, and you *can* apply the Arzela-Ascoli theorem and a diagonal argument to get a locally uniformly convergent subsequence of an equicontinuous family of functions on a $\sigma$-compact space.

Comment: With this answer, and WoolierThanThou's comment in mind, I think this must be a case of bad notation on the author's part. He probably meant to write something like uniform convergence on $[0,T']$, for all $T' \in (0,T)$. Thank you both very much for responding.

Comment: In general, the $L^{\infty}$-topology on the bounded continuous functions on a non-compact but locally compact space is often not very natural, so that seems likely.